# Titanium + GCM : INVALID_SENDER error

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Titanium app development. Now I'm trying to develop push notification app with GCM. I have done,

1. Registered in Google Cloud Console and created one project.
2. Created new server key.
3. Added those keys in ACS console.
4. Created test user in ACS console.

But still I'm getting the following error.

```
Faild to register for push!
INVALID_SENDER
```

My Titanium code:

```
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success : function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        alert('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
        loginDefault();
    },
    error : function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
    }
});
```

Can any one help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: What sender did you use for registering to GCM? You are supposed to use the 12 digits project number.

Comment: While creating new project, I'm not getting a numeric project Id. Instead I'm getting alphanumeric string.

Comment: like `celiular-ring-637`

Comment: I just tried to create a new project. After the project got created, I see at the top of the page something like `Project ID: elite-academy-627 Project Number: 152453929631`. You need the project number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create a new project, you'll see at the top of the page something like this :

`Project ID: elite-academy-627 Project Number: 152453929631`

You need to register to GCM using the project number.